# Children covering Parent element in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a navigation bar with links and sub links. I currently have my links and sub links in the structure `ul` and `li` elements. The drop down navigation bar is designed using JavaScript, which is working as intended, minus one issue. I need the parent element to not disappear when the children element are shown. I have included a screenshot below along with the HTML and JS.

[Children elements covering parent element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOu9P.png)

If someone provides an answer can you also explain why the parent gets covered up? I have tried to find this on stack and looked on the web and was not able to find exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks a bunch guys!

```js
function main(){

  $('.sub-elements').hide();
  $('.main-elements').on('click',function(){
      $(this).children().slideToggle(300);
   });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<div class = "nav-bar">
            <ul class = "nav-drop">
              <li class = "main-elements"><a href = "#">Link 1</a>
                <ul class = "sub-elements">
                  <li><a href = "#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href = "#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class = "main-elements"><a href = "#">Link 2</a>
                <ul class = "sub-elements">
                  <li><a href = "#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href = "#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
                  <li><a href=  "#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
                  <li><a href=  "#">Sub Link 6</a></li>
                </ul>
               </li>
               <li class = "main-elements"><a href='#'>Link 3</a>
                <ul class = "sub-elements">
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 3</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 4</a></li>
               </ul>
             </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

sub links in the structure `ul` and `li` elements. The drop down navigation bar is designed using JavaScript, which is working as intended, minus one issue. I need the parent element to not disappear when the children element are shown. I have included a screenshot below along with the HTML and JS.

[Children elements covering parent element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOu9P.png)

If someone provides an answer can you also explain why the parent gets covered up? I have tried to find this on stack and looked on the web and was not able to find exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks a bunch guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work:

```
function main() {
  $('.sub-elements').hide();

  $('.main-elements').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('.sub-elements').slideToggle(300);
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: What is it about "find" that makes the parent not be hidden?

Comment: I gave that a shot and it worked!  can you explain to me the difference of what find and what children did?

Comment: The children() method returns all direct children of the selected element. (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_children.asp)

Comment: The find() method returns descendant elements of the selected element. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_find.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to add the children class in jQuery

```js
function main(){

$('.sub-elements').hide();
 $('.main-elements').on('click',function(){
  $(this).children('.sub-elements').slideToggle(300);
 });
   }
   $(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "nav-bar">
        <ul class = "nav-drop">
          <li class = "main-elements"><a href = "#">Link 1</a>
            <ul class = "sub-elements">
              <li><a href = "#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href = "#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class = "main-elements"><a href = "#">Link 2</a>
            <ul class = "sub-elements">
              <li><a href = "#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href = "#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href=  "#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
              <li><a href=  "#">Sub Link 6</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li class = "main-elements"><a href='#'>Link 3</a>
            <ul class = "sub-elements">
             <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
             <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
             <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 3</a></li>
             <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 4</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```